# Is there a way in Pandas to slice multiple datetime values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, finance, python-datetime

I have a Dataset of minute prices for EURUSD currency. My prefered timeframe to work with is "60min" so therefore I resample the dataset into 1hr (as below). However, I also want to access the minute data with my new dataset. What I'm looking for is a method where I can pass a time, such as "2019-01-01 17:00:00" and access all minute data within that hour. I have tried to slice my original "Rates" df but get the error message "Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key"

What is the best method to do it?

```
         #import libraries    
            import pandas as pd
            from datetime import datetime
            numpy as np
            
            #read excel
            Rates = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
            #Set columns
            Rates.columns = ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"]
        print(Rates)
        
        Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
        2019-01-01 17:03:00 1.14598 1.14607 1.14598 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:04:00 1.14607 1.14607 1.14606 1.14606 0
        2019-01-01 17:05:00 1.14606 1.14621 1.14606 1.14621 0
        2019-01-01 17:06:00 1.14619 1.14666 1.14604 1.14665 0
        2019-01-01 17:07:00 1.14665 1.14672 1.14607 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:08:00 1.14607 1.14607 1.14606 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:09:00 1.14607 1.14617 1.14606 1.14606 0
        2019-01-01 17:10:00 1.14607 1.14607 1.14607 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:11:00 1.14607 1.14617 1.14606 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:12:00 1.14607 1.14608 1.14607 1.14608 0
        2019-01-01 17:13:00 1.14608 1.14608 1.14607 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:14:00 1.14607 1.14608 1.14607 1.14608 0
        2019-01-01 17:15:00 1.14607 1.14608 1.14607 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:16:00 1.14607 1.14608 1.14607 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:17:00 1.14607 1.14607 1.14607 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:18:00 1.14606 1.14617 1.14606 1.14607 0
        2019-01-01 17:19:00 1.14617 1.14617 1.14606 1.14606 0
        2019-01-01 17:20:00 1.14607 1.14616 1.14606 1.14616 0
        
            
            #Convert "Date" column to DateTime
            DateTime = pd.to_datetime(Rates.Date)
            
            
            #Set index to Datetime object
            Rates.index = DateTime
            
            #Remove previous "Date" Column
            df = Rates.drop(["Date"],axis=1)
            
            #Resample to hourly data
            df = df.resample('1H').first()
    
    print(df)
    
    
    2019-01-01 17:00:00  1.14598  1.14607  1.14598  1.14607     0.0
    2019-01-01 18:00:00  1.14605  1.14653  1.14566  1.14603     0.0
    2019-01-01 19:00:00  1.14612  1.14612  1.14606  1.14606     0.0
    2019-01-01 20:00:00  1.14561  1.14563  1.14559  1.14563     0.0
    2019-01-01 21:00:00  1.14521  1.14524  1.14506  1.14512     0.0

#Now when I have the data resampled, I try to access all minute wise data by slicing.
Rates.iloc[str(df.index[-1])], buy i get the error message: "Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key"
```

My desired output would be to pass a date, ex: "2019-01-01 17:00:00" and then access all minute data within that hour.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `Rates.iloc`? iloc means you want to index by integer indices, i.e. 0,1,2,... which you don't want. Have you tried `Rates[df.index[-1]]` directly?

Comment: Hi! @Fantailed. That works but it only gets me one value. However, I tried with Rates[str(df.index[-1]):df.index[-1] + timedelta(minutes=59)] and got my desired output. Thanks for the help!